# ¿Como guardar y leer una IP solo cuando el ultimo rango de la IP tenga una diferencia de 10?

Tags: php, php5, ip

No se si la pregunta este bien formulada, pero con el codigo de aqui abajo, obtengo la IP del usuario y la guardo en un archivo .txt. y cuando el usuario intenta entrar nuevamente, lee el archivo .txt y le lanza un mensaje diciendo que ya su IP ha sido usada. lo que quiero hacer es que si la IP guardada es por ejemplo: 192.168.1.10, y la ip del usuario es 192.168.1.15. le diga lo mismo que si la ip estuviera guardada, pero si su IP es por ejemplo: 192.168.1.21. entonces si la guarde y le permita visitar el enlace. es decir que el ultimo rango de numeros de la ip, tenga que tener una diferencia de al menos 10.

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$file = file_get_contents( "ips.txt" );
$archivo = "ips.txt";
$proceso = fopen($archivo, "a");
$datos   = "".$ip."\n";

if( preg_match( "/$ip/", $file ) ) {
    echo "Esta IP ha sido usada recientemente, cambia la IP.";

}
    else{
    header ('Location: https://www.ejemplo.com/?view=ad1');
    fwrite($proceso, $datos);
    fclose($proceso);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si te he entendido bien, lo que necesitas es quitarle el ultimo byte a la dirección, por lo que lo más comodo sería que usaras un Substring.

```
$ip = substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, -2);
```

Edit:

Respondiendo a la pregunta, tendrías que utilizar substring otra vez, pero ahora de manera distinta.

Lo primero sería leer el archivo y comprobar que no está vacio, después comprobar que la IP nueva sea mínimo 10 digitos mas pequeña y luego ejecutar el resto de tu código.

```
  $file = file_get_contents("ips.txt");
  if(filesize($file)!=0){
    $file = substr(file_get_contents("ips.txt"), 10, 1);
    $ip = substr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], 0, -2);
    $archivo = "ips.txt";
    $proceso = fopen($archivo, "a");
    $datos   = "".$ip."\n";

      if($ip>$file+10){
        if( preg_match( "/$ip/", $file ) ) {
          echo "Esta IP ha sido usada recientemente, cambia la IP.";        
        }
        else{
          header ('Location: https://www.ejemplo.com/?view=ad1');
          fwrite($proceso, $datos);
          fclose($proceso);
        }
      }  
  }
  else{
     echo "archivo vacio";
  }
```

PS: Debería ser algo similar a esto.

Comment: Correcto, ya lo habia logrado con esto: `$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ips = substr($ip, 0, strrpos($ip, '.'));`. pero el tuyo tambien funciona

Comment: Sabes si hay alguna forma de hacerlo diferente, osea como si la ip guardada es 192.168.1.10. y mi ip es 192.168.1.15. no me lo permita. pero si mi ip fuera 192.168.1.21, si me permita. es decir que los numeros despues del ultimo punto esten alejado por 10 minimo

Comment: Esa es una buena pregunta, edita tu post preguntando eso también así cualquiera podrá verlo y te respondo en mi comentario.

Comment: Ya cambie el post y la pregunta

Comment: Si la primera vez la ip es 192.168.1.15 y la segunda vez es 192.168.1.218 y estás haciendo un substring a los 2 últimos caracteres no te valdría esta logica.

Comment: No esta funcionando, no guarda la ip en el archivo .txt